# How do I stop the dot from printing after the last letter?

Tags: python, generator

```
printmystring = ""

mystring = input("Enter the sentence you wish to be an acronym: ")

mystring_length = len(mystring)

for i in range (0,mystring_length):
    if  mystring[i].isupper():
        print(mystring[i] ,end="")
        print(".",end="")
```

My input is "For Your Information"

The output is F.Y.I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will work:

```
mystring = input("Enter the sentence you wish to be an acronym: ")

mystring_length = len(mystring)

print(mystring[0] ,end="")

for i in range (1,mystring_length):
    if mystring[i].isupper():
        print(". " ,end="") 
        print(mystring[i],end="")
```

Comment: Thanks so much :D didnt know it was this simple.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems pretty complicated for such a small task.

Let me present a different solution where we gather all upper letters in a list.

```
mystring = input("Enter the sentence you wish to be an acronym: ")
upper_letters = [letter for letter in mystring if letter.isupper()]
print('.'.join(upper_letters))
```

Another way to go was suggested by moarningsun:

```
upper_letters = filter(str.isupper, mystring)
```

Comment: You can also use `filter` together with `str.isupper` for even shorter code

Comment: Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this:

```
#initialize variables
buffer = ""
words = list()

#get input
mystring = input("Enter the sentence you wish to be an acronym: ")
mystring_length = len(mystring)

#parse words
for i in range (0, mystring_length)
     if mystring[i] == " "
         words.append(buffer)
         buffer = ""
     else
         buffer += mystring[i]

#add the final word to buffer
#as it is not followed by a space, it will not be added using the above algorithm
words.append(buffer)
buffer = ""

#loop through words
for i in range (0, len(words))
     print(words[i], end="")
     if (i != len(words))
          print(".", end="")
```

Edited for python (i think)

Answer (score 0):

```
def acronym(sentence):
    return '.'.join([x[0].upper() for x in sentence.split()])
```